# Как получить url из базы данных Firebase

Tags: android

Есть вот такая база данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Авторизация снята, полный доступ. Написал вот так и дальше застрял....

```
public void onClick(View view) {

        // [START initialize_database_ref]
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        // [END initialize_database_ref]
    ValueEventListener bookListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {


        }
    };

    // Загружаем картинку
    Picasso.with(this)
            .load(coverUrl)
    .into(mImageView);
```

Как получить url любой записи из этой базы? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Все данные в `Firebase` суть `JSON`
2. `JSON` имеет древовидную структуру.
3. Данные получаются асинхронно, через колбэки слушателей, повешенных на узел в структуре данных.
4. Данные приходят в аргументе `DataSnapshot dataSnapshot` откуда их надо вытаскивать по ключу (т.к. данные хранятся в виде пар ключ-значение), указав, какой тип данных вы ожидаете. Это может быть примитив, простой объект типа `String`, `Date` etc или свой класс, написанный по определённым правилам.

Псевдокод из вышеизложенного (я не помню точных названий методов):

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    //формируем ссылку на узел в БД с книгами
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("books");
    //создаём слушатель изменений в БД. В него придут все подузлы узла books
    //в его колбэке вытаскиваем ссылку и отображаем картинку по этой ссылке
    ValueEventListener bookListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //получили книгу, берём её поле coverUrl и получаем его в виде строки
            String url = dataSnapshot.child("coverUrl").getValue(String.class);

            // Загружаем картинку
            Picasso.with(view.getContext())
                .load(url)
                .into(mImageView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
           //log error here and handle it somehow
        }
    };
    //вешаем наш слушатель на нашу ссылку
    ref.addValueEventListener(bookListener);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Немного поправил формирование ссылки на узел в БД, добавил еще один чайлд: 
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("books").child("book_1");

Comment: @Вячеслав, если ответ помог, то вы можете отметить его верным, нажав галочку слева от тела ответа)

Comment: Да, так и сделал)) Еще раз спасибо!